# Get first object in nullable array

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array like this:

```
episodes?: Episode[];
```

In a function I want to get the first object in that array. I have tried the following:

```
let episode: Episode = this.episodes?[0];
```

or

```
var episode = this.episodes?[0];
```

However these both gives the following error:

> Error: src/app/episodes/episodes.component.ts:30:45 - error TS1005: ':' expected.

How do I get an item from this array?

Comment: have you tried this? `this.episodes?.[0]` (note the dot after the `?`).

Answer (score 5):

You need a `.`

```
this.episodes?.[0];
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAomCWBnA9gE2gXigbwLACgopEIBDFAOwC4oKBXAWwCMIAnAo+hmrl9-AL4ECoSFACyIAPJMAVlCx5CUCAhTpEAfhpwkaCAG0AugG4CQ-AXQBjADalW0a8gqJgUBtLkRrwGpJlZAlsId1U9dB01fQUPL1kfYAA6cPUILSSDAAZTAiA)

---

However, you'll still have a type error in:

```
let episode: Episode = this.episodes?.[0];
```

This is because the result of the right side might be `undefined`. How to handle that is up to you. But somehow you'll need to handle the fact that the type is `Episode | undefined`.

For example, you'd have to test the value to see if it exists first:

```
let episode = this.episodes?.[0];
if (episode) {
  console.log(episode.season) // works
} else {
  throw new Error("one episode is required!")
}
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAomCWBnA9gE2gXigbwLACgopEIBDFAOwC4oKBXAWwCMIAnAo+hmrl9-AL4ECoSFACyIAPJMAVlCx5CUCAhTpEAfhpwkaCAG0AugG4CQ-AXQBjADalW0a8gqJgUBtLkRrwGpJlZYXxbCHdVPXQFDy9ZH2AAOgj1CC0EgwAGUwJ4ADMoAApk-QBKHA4oZ1dkUITbZABzIrV9BJJyFzKAei6oAHdkVgBrRHMVWxJy5WAAC1ZkPtoIRZhWedYCgCIXaGKopChHAEc6eEdUAEJNkvNgoA)

Comment: This now gives me the error: `Type 'Episode | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Episode'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Episode'.ts(2322)`.

Comment: you need undefined in your type I believe: `type Episode = {
  season: number
  num: number
} | undefined`

Comment: `Episode` is an interface.

Comment: Since `episodes` is optional, you have to handle the `undefined` case somewhere. See my updated answer

Comment: Thanks Alex, that's done the trick.